# use javascript data in tableView Swift

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

hello i'm new with swift programming and have the following issue. I read about how i can get data from safari in my action extension. using code inside viewDidLoad. so far so good.

i build a tableView with a tutorial and it works fine.

know i would like to use data data i extracted form safari in to my tableView. The problem is that my tableView is loaded first and after that my data is pulled from safari.

how can i use the data directly in my TableView?

here my code. beware i am new at this and it is under construction. The tableVie is now filled with information as demonstrated in the tutorial.

```
import UIKit
```

import MobileCoreServices

var webDataArray : [String] = []

class ActionViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

var arrayOfWebData: [CustomCellContents] = [CustomCellContents]()
var effectStannd = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for item: AnyObject in self.extensionContext!.inputItems {
        let inputItem = item as! NSExtensionItem
        for provider: AnyObject in inputItem.attachments! {
            let itemProvider = provider as! NSItemProvider
            if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypePropertyList as! String) {
                itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier(kUTTypePropertyList as! String, options: nil, completionHandler: {(list, error) in
                    if let results = list as? NSDictionary {
                            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
                                var webData = results.description
                                webDataArray = split(webData) {$0 == ","}
                                var testArray = split(webDataArray[0]) {$0 == " "}
                                webDataArray.removeAtIndex(0)
                                webDataArray.append(testArray[7])
                                testArray = split(webDataArray[13]) {$0 == " "}
                                webDataArray.removeAtIndex(13)
                                webDataArray.append(testArray[1])
                                //println(webDataArray)
                                println(webDataArray.count)
                            }
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
    }
    println(webDataArray.count)
    self.setUpWebData()
    self.addEffect()
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func done() {
    // Return any edited content to the host app.
    // This template doesn't do anything, so we just echo the passed in items.
    self.extensionContext!.completeRequestReturningItems(self.extensionContext!.inputItems, completionHandler: nil)
}

func setUpWebData()
{
    var webData1 = CustomCellContents(fileName: "Torrent", fileKind: "img1.jpeg")
    var webData2 = CustomCellContents(fileName: "Magnet", fileKind: "img2.jpeg")
    var webData3 = CustomCellContents(fileName: "Exe", fileKind: "img1.jpeg")
    var webData4 = CustomCellContents(fileName: "DMG", fileKind: "img2.jpeg")

    arrayOfWebData.append(webData1)
    arrayOfWebData.append(webData2)
    arrayOfWebData.append(webData3)
    arrayOfWebData.append(webData4)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return arrayOfWebData.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CustomCell

    let CustomCellContents = arrayOfWebData[indexPath.row]

    cell.setCell(CustomCellContents.fileName, imageName: CustomCellContents.fileKind)

    return cell
}


/////// Custom swip from Right
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]?
{
    var shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Download") { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

        let firstActivityItem = self.arrayOfWebData[indexPath.row]

        let activityViewControler = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [firstActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)

        self.presentViewController(activityViewControler, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

shareAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

return [shareAction]

}


//// de volgende functie zorgt ervoor dat de rij automatisch word gedeselecteerd
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    self.myTableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}


func addEffect(){
    if effectStannd{
        var effect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
        var effectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: effect)
        effectView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 600)
        view.addSubview(effectView)
        effectStannd = false
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in refreshing my tableview after loading. It works fine like this.

```
func didRefreshList(){
    var tableView = myTableView
    self.tableData = webDataArray3
    tableView.reloadData()
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```